# Add 13 hours to a timestamp

Tags: php, time

I have a table with timestamp values like:

```
    2009-07-14 02:00:00
```

I need to display them at run time with 13 hours added, like:

```
    2009-07-14 15:00:00
```

What's the simplest way to do this in PHP?

Comment: 07-14 02:00 to 07-15 13:00 is 35 hours, not 13. How do you count it?

Comment: ahh oops it was only an example.. my bad! i just need to know how to add x hours to a timestamp (not the current time)!

Comment: If anyone's still looking for this, the better way is Richy B.'s method, viz.: `$date = new DateTime('2009-07-14 02:00:00'); $date->add(new DateInterval('P13H'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this was asked a long time ago and I had already chosen the answer, but I believed it's important to point new users in a more modern and correct direction, which is using the fantastic [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) library:

```
>>> Carbon\Carbon::parse('2009-07-14 02:00:00')
... ->addHours(13)
... ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
=> Carbon\Carbon {#869
     +"date": "2009-07-14 15:00:00.000000",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "UTC",
   }
```

Carbon not only makes it simpler to perform the requested calculation, it also shields you against any potential mistakes you may make while manually trying to do the same thing.

The shell in the above output example is Laravel Tinker. Laravel ships with Carbon, so the above statement works out-of-the-box. If you're not using a modern PHP framework, you should be. It's easy to add Carbon to it.

Answer (score 22):

I know that

```
date( "Y-M-d H:i:s", strtotime( $timestamp_from_array ) + 13 * 3600 );
```

is smelly, but it will give you an idea.

`strtotime` converts the timestamp string to a timestamp value, then we add the hours and convert it back to the timestamp format in the array with the `date` function.

But I suppose what you really want is to use [time zones](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/datetimezone.getoffset.php).

Edit:
[igstan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124752/1124811#1124811) is correct, you should also mind the daylight saving time changes between those offsets.

Answer (score 17):

There are lots of problems with Time Zones and Daylight Saving Time when using basic arithmetic for time calculations. The best solution is to rely on PHP's own date/time functions, like [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or [mktime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php). I wrote about [DST problems on my blog](http://igstan.ro/posts/2008-12-20-how-not-to-use-dates-in-php.html).

```
echo date('Y-M-d H:i:s', strtotime('2009-07-14 02:00:00 + 13 hours'));
```

Comment: "+ 13 hours", what a fantastic and simple solution! (Upvoted)

Answer (score 2):

Can you do the add as it comes out of the database?

```
SELECT ... DateAdd(hh, 13, DateField) AS DateField
```

(SQL Server)

Comment: too costly on the server end, don't you think?

Comment: IMHO, this one is better as the data is "correct" as soon as it comes back from the query.  There's no opportunity to do something else on accident or forget to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

you could use http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php to convert it to a unix timestamp.
Then you could easily add 13*60*60 to that and use http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to convert it back to a timestamp as you like.

another way would be via the explode function, but i think this might be more complicated because you have to look if days/month/years change and stuff

Comment: yeah i don't want to manually do it unless i have to. lemme try the other method you mentioned.

Comment: +1, thought for date format given, strtotime would work just as well

Comment: -1, you should not use basic arithmetic for time calculations. Due to Daylight Saving Time some bugs my sneak in. I've wrote about it: http://igstan.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-not-to-make-dates-in-php.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a table with the timestamps? If it's a MySQL database, you could just do this in the database using [addtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime): `SELECT ADDTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999', '1 1:1:1.000002');`

If you are using the PHP Zend Framework, you could do something like:

```
 $date=new Zend_Date(Array('year'=>$iYear,'month'=>$iMonth,'day'=>$iDay));
 // changes $date by adding 12 hours
 $date->add('12:00:00', Zend_Date::TIMES);
```

Alternatively, you could do it using native PHP4 functions such as:
[faster, less accurate: doesn't account for leap seconds/time zone changes etc]

```
$datestamp=strtotime('2009-07-14 02:00:00'); // It'll probably be better using mktime
$datestamp=$datestamp+(60*60*13); // 60 seconds times 60 minutes times 13 hours
```

or
[slower, more accurate]

```
  $datestamp = strtotime('2009-07-14 02:00:00'); // It'll probably be better using mktime
  $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:S', mktime(date('H',$datestamp)+13, date('i',$datestamp), date('s',$datestamp), date('m',$datestamp), date('d',$datestamp), date('Y',$datestamp)));
```

or, if you are using PHP 5 using the [Datetime](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) functions

```
$date = new DateTime('2009-07-14 02:00:00');
date_add($date, new DateInterval("P13H"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+13 hours', strtotime('2009-07-14 02:00:00')));
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you were picking a specific date field from your table called "*datetime_field*" from row ID 3000. It would be as simple as this!

```
SELECT *, ADDTIME(`datetime_field`,'0 13:00:00') as new_datetime
FROM `table_name`
WHERE id = 3000
```

This can obviously be used in update queries too if one wanted to update, of course.

And alternatively, if you were just adding 13 hours (timezone differences) to the query. One would use the MySQL *NOW()* as the original time and simply add the time like above. *Selecting, updating, or inserting,* it's all the same methodology! It would be:

```
SELECT *, NOW() as current_datetime,
          ADDTIME(NOW(),'0 13:00:00') as new_datetime
FROM `table_name`
WHERE id = 3000
```

*Keep it simple and fast !*

:o)