# Mysql Timpestamp plus time

Tags: mysql

On MySql when I run "INSERT" I want to set the date to " Current time stamp " + 1 minuts

I am able to insert the time like this 2017-02-23 00:00:00 but I want it to be added like this 2017-02-23 00:01:00

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql methods *NOW()*,*CURDATE()*,*CURTIME()* to get current date and after that you can use another method

```
DATE_ADD( date, INTERVAL value unit )
```

where date is current date, value unit you can put MINUTE like this

```
DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your insert you can use `now() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE` to correctly set your required date, something like

```
INSERT INTO table (id, insert_time) VALUES (1, now() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Or just use search  - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124752/add-13-hours-to-a-timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124752/add-13-hours-to-a-timestamp)

Comment: @Goku this is actually php not mysql

Comment: so which programming language you use for connecting to MySql?

Comment: What should that mean? You can use mysql directly without any programming language, here we are talking about mysql ad not php

Comment: OK, sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE_ADD function. For example :

```
INSERT INTO table(date) VALUES(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

Or if you already have the date

```
INSERT INTO table(date) VALUES('2017-02-23 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

Have a look to MySQL documentation for more details :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select ADDDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),INTERVAL 1 minute)
```

ADDDATE used to add intervals of particular timestamp.Please refer this link http://w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-adddate-function.php

for example  `select ADDDATE('2017-01-01 00:01:00',INTERVAL 1 minute)`

the result is `'2017-01-01 00:02:00'`

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.